# Dictionary for <string, image>, WP8

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to create a dictionary with a key/value of string / image for Windows Phone 8.

I understand how dictionaries work, but am unsure of which type I would use for my image.

Essentially, I'm trying to create 26 images, 1 for each letter of the alphabet, so that apple corresponds to an image of an apple.

I'm confused with how to do this on WP8 though, so any guidance in the correct direction would be appreciated

**Update:** Thank you for the answer. I've still got to be doing something wrong here. For example:

```
    //Set up the dictionary of AlphaImages objects. 
    if (AlphaImages == null)
    {
        AlphaImages = new Dictionary<string, BitmapImage>();
        AlphaImages.Add("Apple", new BitmapImage(@"Apple.jpg"));
    }
```

It claims that Im using invalid arguments for the BitmapImage.
 [Following along with this thread,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963706/adding-multiple-bitmap-values-for-one-key-in-dictionary-with-c-sharp) the user takes a different approach with this code:

```
Dictionary<string, Bitmap> lookup = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
lookup.Add("A", new Bitmap(@"C:\08\letters\1\a1.bmp", true));
```

and I'm unable to get that to work as well, as the compiler spits out the same error.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: WP8 doesn't have bitmap as far as I know. All I see are BitConverter and BitMapCache, which is why I'm confused.

Comment: So, your issues has actually nothing to do with `Dictionary`, you're asking about images?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. That explains my confusion, thank you.

*Also, how do I mark your comment as the correct answer? I'd like to give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

AlphaImages.Add("Apple", new BitmapImage(new Uri("Apple.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));

make sure the image is set to have a Build Action of Content.

Air-coded. :)

Also, see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2011/04/07/image-tips-for-windows-phone-7.aspx)

Comment: I thought it was exactly that, as I explored a bit more. 

I figured that it was just a very sloppy looking way of doing it, but it works perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`BitmapImage` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).